# By using semantic-react inputs. How to use redux to store values/information in store/state?

Tags: reactjs, input, redux, store, semantic-ui-react

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KluF9.png)

Does anyone have example code of using semantic-react inputs and storing values/informatoin in store/state by using redux?

Comment: Please do not post code as an image

Comment: ... and not as comment either. :-) Editing the question makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest a better learning approach.  Instead of asking "How do I use Semantic-UI-React inputs with Redux", the right question is "How do I correctly use forms in React?".  I'd encourage you to read through [Gosha Arinich's articles on React forms](https://goshakkk.name/on-forms-react/), particularly the post on ["controlled" and "uncontrolled" inputs](https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/).

Once you have set up a form with controlled inputs that keeps the data in React component state, you can expand on that to switch the data to be in Redux instead.  Replace calling `this.setState()` with dispatching a Redux action, and replace `<input value={this.state.someValue}>` with `<input value={this.props.someValue}>`, where the props data is coming from Redux.

My ["Practical Redux" blog series](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/series/practical-redux/) demonstrates examples of forms that get their data from Redux, particularly:

- [Practical Redux, Part 6: Connected Lists, Forms, and Performance](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/)
- [Practical Redux, Part 7: Form Change Handling and Data Editing](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-7-forms-editing-reducers/)
- [Practical Redux, Part 8: Form Draft Data Management](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-8-form-draft-data-management/)

As a bonus, the "Practical Redux" series also happens to use Semantic-UI-React, but the principles of using controlled inputs should work no matter what specific library you're using to generate the inputs.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you use [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/) to place your form state into Redux. All of the tools included in that library are likely going to be more useful to you. It has form validation, allows you to see if a form is dirty, etc.

Here's an example of how redux-form would be used with SUIR and form validation. This is above what you are trying to do, but your simple implementation is also included in the example. https://gist.github.com/mairh/233f6b4ffdbaaed8ec75bb0bef087e8f

Comment: I disagree. Redux-Form is a powerful library, but it's overkill for the vast majority of applications, and it's a bad idea to recommend it immediately for someone who has some simple forms.  It's better for them to understand the core principles of using forms in React, and then expand on that to put the form data in the Redux store instead of React component state.

Comment: Disagreeing is fine. I am missing the part of your response where you propose a better answer.

Comment: As I said: explaining how to correctly use forms in React as a whole, and then extrapolating on that to getting the information from Redux.